# How to sync Google Calendar and iCloud Calendar

Tags: icloud, calendar, google-calendar

Is there a way to have a Google calendar and iCloud calendar sync *such that changes made to one is reflected in the other, and vice versa*?

I can do this with Fastmail and iCloud (see [How to synchronize a calendar](https://www.fastmail.help/hc/en-us/articles/360058752754-How-to-synchronize-a-calendar)). But I cannot figure it out with Google and iCloud. I have searched online for a while but all results are about *seeing* my Google calendar on my Apple device or vice versa. To be clear, I want my Google calendar to always be identical to my iCloud calendar.